# GeoServer (GeoPackage) + Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, vector, tiles, geopackage

I have placed 10 geopackage files locally on GeoServer. I also added a plugin for vector tiles. Tell me the code to open them via Leaflet and that when you click on the object there is information.

Comment: I have a few geojson examples but not a geopackage.  They are similar but the leaflet site has a better example.

Comment: The example you are looking for may be here. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202165/how-to-load-tiles-from-geopackage-properly-using-openlayers3-and-geopackage-js?rq=1

Comment: @CaryH The example you are referring to in your comment is for OpenLayers, not for Leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the tutorial from here - https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js/tree/master/leaflet

```
// Load the Rivers GeoPackage and display the tile layer
L.geoPackageTileLayer({
    geoPackageUrl: 'http://ngageoint.github.io/GeoPackage/examples/rivers.gpkg',
    layerName: 'rivers_tiles'
}).addTo(map);

// Load the Rivers GeoPackage and display the feature layer
L.geoPackageFeatureLayer([], {
    geoPackageUrl: 'http://ngageoint.github.io/GeoPackage/examples/rivers.gpkg',
    layerName: 'rivers'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Did this tutorial but not postgis and as I understand the request is not to getpackage and to wms. https://www.earder.com/tutorials/postgis_geoserver_leaflet/ Which path should I prescribe?

Answer (score 0):

You can [publish](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/vector/geopkg.html) the GeoPackages through GeoServer as with any other [datastore](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/vector/index.html). Once you have done so [Leaflet can request them as WMS layers](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html) in many different output formats including [vector tiles](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html). You may find it easier to start out with simple image layers and build up to more complex ones like vector tiles as you become more experienced.